# Matching date and time using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches the date and time in this format - d/m/Y H:m am/pm. For example, `1/2/2020 1.30pm`

This is the regex I am using but it does not match the date and time specified in the example -

```
$value = '1/2/2020 1.30pm';
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4} (0\d|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)(?::((?2)))?\h*([ap]m)? $/", $value) === 0) {
     return false;
}else{
     return true;
}
```

Please kindly help correct my mistakes on the regex expression

Comment: What strikes me at first is that your example uses `/` in the date when you use `-` in the regex.

Comment: @Éric It was a typo. I have corrected

Comment: I suggest simplifying the format to allow all sort of numbers and validating the date afterwards. Now, you prevent invalid time, but your date can still be invalid.

Comment: @radioactive, Also you have a `.` to separate hours and minutes in your example, when you use a `:` in your regex.

Comment: Does the value *have* to be in that format? Why not just simplify to `return strtotime($value) !== false;`?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are lots of ways to validate the date, in addition to matching; you could find some different approaches.  Here is a regex that will match your date, regardless of what you use to separate the numbers.  \W indicates any "non-word character" will match -, or / or anything so long as it isn't a letter, digit or underscore.  The ? will match 0 or 1, and the * will match zero or more.

```
^\d+\W\d+\W\d+\s+\d+\W?\d+\w*
```

Will match all of these:

```
01/02/2020 11:45am

01-02-2020 10.33pm

1-23-68 2345

09/30/2323 23:15
```

Cheers!
Kylie

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about some freedom in the format (like accepting both `pm` and `PM`), you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`:

```php
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y g.ia', $value);
$isValid = $dateTime !== false;
```